# Cant set S3 Url to Path Style with PaperClip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

Always getting this error:

```
Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError in HomeController#import
hostname "loopimgstore2.s3.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate
```

Tried everything, current config in environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {

```
 89     storage: :s3,
 90     s3_protocol: 'http',
 91     url: '":s3_path_url"',                                                                                                                 
 92     #s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
 93     s3_permissions: :public_read,
 94     s3_region: 's3-eu-west-1',
 95     s3_credentials: {
 96       bucket: 'loopimgstore2',
 97       access_key_id: '____',
 98       secret_access_key: '____'
 99     }
100   }
```

For some reason I can't configure Paperclip to USE Path style url, it is always using domain style and it's clearly not working.

Comment: have you read this ? http://www.theverge.com/2017/3/2/14792442/amazon-s3-outage-cause-typo-internet-server

Comment: @falsify yes but it's not relevant now. That was like 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This worked for me

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_region => ENV['AWS_S3_REGION'],
  :s3_credentials => {
    :s3_host_name => ENV['AWS_S3_HOST_NAME'],
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}

In `.env` file
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='Access key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='secret access key'
AWS_S3_REGION='your s3 region for e.g. us-east-1'
AWS_S3_HOST_NAME='s3 host name for e.g. s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_BUCKET='s3 bucket name'
```

Comment: It didn't work Still giving me "hostname "loopimgstore2.s3.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate"